# Rails Dev in WSL (Windows) constantly losing Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wanted to try out WSL and Rail Dev on a Windows machine and finally got it working.

However, every time I leave the directory, or open a new WSL, it informs me 
`Required ruby-2.6.5 is not installed.` - Trying to install it either using rbenv or rvm both said it is already installed, and ask me to over-write. It will fail every time unless I also uninstall and re-install OpenSSL.

How can I get this continuous cycle of deletion to stop?

**Error When Re-installing 2.6.5 without reinstalling OpenSSL**

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.6.5/ext/openssl'
exts.mk:243: recipe for target 'ext/openssl/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
linking shared-object ripper.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.6.5/ext/ripper'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.6.5'
uncommon.mk:286: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```